Can't click on 'create' | pycharm remote interpreter
I'm trying to add a new ssh interpreter, so I can connect with the same credentials with putty and the pycharm terminal, but the interpreter ssh won't let me click on create at the end.
step 1
step 2
step 3
step 4
and now I can't click on create.
I did notice if i spam the button this pops up for a mil sec:
creating helpers dir
and if I click on the 3 dots at the end of the "Base interpreter" line:
idk
I checked all the paths if they are correct, I tried connecting via pycharm terminal and my normal cmd / terminal and putty and everything works.

Additional information from the logs is required here. Feel free to create a new bug report on YouTrack - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=PY
